# Fatal error: mysql error: [0: Connection error to server 'localhost' with user 'use_online']

Tags: php, mysql, adodb-php

i got this error message

```
 Fatal error: mysql error: [0: Connection error to server 'localhost' with user 'use_online'] in CONNECT(localhost, '****', '****', use_home) in /home/usr/public_html/libraries/adodb/adodb-errorhandler.inc.php on line 81
```

im using adodb

my code

```
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/adodb/adodb-errorhandler.inc.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/adodb/adodb.inc.php');

$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->NConnect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$sql = "SELECT * from config";

$rsc = $conn->Execute($sql);
```

it was working fine but win i move to new server it gave me the errors above

**update**

adodb.inc.php code
.......................................................

```
/**************************************************************************************************
| Edited By : Onlinewp
| http://onlinewp.com
|**************************************************************************************************/


/**
 * @version V3.40 7 April 2003  (c) 2000-2003 John Lim (jlim@natsoft.com.my). All rights reserved.
 * Released under both BSD license and Lesser GPL library license.
  Whenever there is any discrepancy between the two licenses,
  the BSD license will take precedence.
 *
 * Set tabs to 4 for best viewing.
 *
 * Latest version is available at http://php.weblogs.com
 *
*/

// added Claudio Bustos  clbustos#entelchile.net
if (!defined('ADODB_ERROR_HANDLER_TYPE')) define('ADODB_ERROR_HANDLER_TYPE',E_USER_ERROR); 

define('ADODB_ERROR_HANDLER','ADODB_Error_Handler');

  /**
* Default Error Handler. This will be called with the following params
*
* @param $dbms      the RDBMS you are connecting to
* @param $fn        the name of the calling function (in uppercase)
* @param $errno     the native error number from the database
* @param $errmsg    the native error msg from the database
* @param $p1        $fn specific parameter - see below
* @param $P2        $fn specific parameter - see below
    */
function ADODB_Error_Handler($dbms, $fn, $errno, $errmsg, $p1, $p2, &$thisConnection)
{
    if (error_reporting() == 0) return; // obey @ protocol
    switch($fn) {
    case 'EXECUTE':
        $sql = $p1;
        $inputparams = $p2;

        $s = "$dbms error: [$errno: $errmsg] in $fn(\"$sql\")\n";
        break;

    case 'PCONNECT':
    case 'CONNECT':
        $host = $p1;
        $database = $p2;

        $s = "$dbms error: [$errno: $errmsg] in $fn($host, '****', '****', $database)\n";
        break;
    default:
        $s = "$dbms error: [$errno: $errmsg] in $fn($p1, $p2)\n";
        break;
    }
    /*
    * Log connection error somewhere
    *   0 message is sent to PHP's system logger, using the Operating System's system
    *       logging mechanism or a file, depending on what the error_log configuration
    *       directive is set to.
    *   1 message is sent by email to the address in the destination parameter.
    *       This is the only message type where the fourth parameter, extra_headers is used.
    *       This message type uses the same internal function as mail() does.
    *   2 message is sent through the PHP debugging connection.
    *       This option is only available if remote debugging has been enabled.
    *       In this case, the destination parameter specifies the host name or IP address
    *       and optionally, port number, of the socket receiving the debug information.
    *   3 message is appended to the file destination
    */
    if (defined('ADODB_ERROR_LOG_TYPE')) {
        $t = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if (defined('ADODB_ERROR_LOG_DEST'))
            error_log("($t) $s", ADODB_ERROR_LOG_TYPE, ADODB_ERROR_LOG_DEST);
        else
            error_log("($t) $s", ADODB_ERROR_LOG_TYPE);
    }


    //print "<p>$s</p>";
    trigger_error($s,ADODB_ERROR_HANDLER_TYPE); 
}
```

Comment: Did you try to create new user on moved server and in moved server do you have same user name for mysql ?

Comment: As the message says: The error occurs in "/home/usr/public_html/libraries/adodb/adodb-errorhandler.inc.php on line 81". Your code snipped includes that file. So it shows nothing.

Comment: @IvanBarayev i have same user name for mysql  and i have create  new user for testing

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone added